# Transform Textual Data from RunProcess to an Image

Tags: import, data, png-format

I'm working with [xPDF](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/), which has a simple pdf to png converter.

[image]

The problem is that the output (`tt`) is not a PNG String, and i can't do: `Image[tt,"PNG"]` to get the actually image.

When i do

```
StringFormat[tt]
```

It says that the string is in Binary Format

---

Pr1 is the path for pdftopng.exe and FT is the PDF file's path

---

Edit 1: I could save the output image in a specific file, but i didn't wanted to have a lot of temp png files

Comment: Have you tried `ImportString[tt,"PNG"]`?

Comment: @b3m2a1 yes! didn't work, it's like a "escaped text". I need something to "unescape" the text